# Android Relative Layout Selector

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

How do I change the color of a Relative Layout Shape ? To work it like a button.
I tried to do it using a selector.

This is the code i used.

```
       <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/rlGPS"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/relative_selector"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvs1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvl1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv1"
                android:text="you can here protect ... "
                android:textColor="@color/gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvl1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv1"
                android:text="GPS"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

relative_selector.xml  In here I'm doing the changes using selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 


  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/relative_focus"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false"
   android:drawable="@drawable/relative_clicked" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/relative_background"/>

</selector>
```

relative_background.xml This is the shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:shape="rectangle">

 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#636161" />

 <padding android:left="5dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="5dp" />

 <corners android:radius="6dp" />

 <solid android:color="#88ffffff"
     />

</shape>
```

In "relative_clicked.xml" and "relative_focus.xml" I only changed the colors.

relative_focus.xml

```
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffff00" />
```

relative_clicked.xml

```
      <solid android:color="#88ffff00"/>
```

All .xml files are in drawable folder.
I want to work this like a button.Is someone having any idea?

Comment: "But it's not working" is a useless description of the problem. Please take the time to provide **precise, specific symptoms**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your selector xml:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:state_enabled="false" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/relative_clicked" />
```

Will it work if you remove `state_enabled`?

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/relative_clicked" />
```

Comment: Oh Yep yep it's working.Thnks.Still focusing part not working